# MSAL not storing token in cache

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-ad-msal, wsl-2

This is the code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

var scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
var clientId = "4a1aa1d5-c567-49d0-ad0b-cd957a47f842";
var tenant = "common";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApp;
AuthenticationResult authResult;

publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
  .WithAuthority(authority)
  .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080")
  .Build();

var accounts = await publicClientApp
  .GetAccountsAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);
IAccount? firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

authResult = await publicClientApp
  .AcquireTokenInteractive(new string[] { "user.read" })
  .ExecuteAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);

authResult = await publicClientApp
  .AcquireTokenSilent(new string[] { "user.read" }, firstAccount)
  .ExecuteAsync();
```

This is the exception that is being thrown:

```
Unhandled exception. MSAL.NetCore.4.44.0.0.MsalUiRequiredException: 
        ErrorCode: user_null
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ClientApplicationBaseExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenSilentParameters silentParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /home/adrian/temp/microsoft-identity-platform/simpler-version-public/Program.cs:line 25
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
        StatusCode: 0 
        ResponseBody:  
        Headers:
```

The csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>simpler_version_public</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.44.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My understanding is that calling `AcquireTokenInteractive()` should automatically store the token in the cache, and `AcquireTokenSilent()` gets the token from the cache. Why am I getting the error then? I am running this code in WSL, and `dotnet --version` returns `6.0.300`.

Comment: That error has a bunch of google hits, have you checked them out yet?

Comment: @Crowcoder I only use StackOverflow as a last resort when I can't figure out the problem myself with/without Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `GetAccountsAsync` before `AcquireTokenInteractive` and it doesn't return any account. No account is passed to `AcquireTokenSilent` and this method doesn't know for which account should be access token acquired.

You need to call `GetAccountsAsync` after you call `AcquireTokenInteractive`. In that case it will return the account and `AcquireTokenSilent` will acquire the token from the cache for the specified account.

```
authResult = await publicClientApp
  .AcquireTokenInteractive(new string[] { "user.read" })
  .ExecuteAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);

var accounts = await publicClientApp
  .GetAccountsAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);
IAccount? firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();    

authResult = await publicClientApp
  .AcquireTokenSilent(new string[] { "user.read" }, firstAccount)
  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the examples that Microsoft provides in the Github repository, you only have to use [`app.AddInMemoryTokenCache()`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/blob/f557263fcdd3321f898c8f710bb54f10e2965bba/1-Call-MSGraph/daemon-console/Program.cs#L72) with `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`,  and [`new StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder(...).WithLinuxKeyring(...)`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-desktop-tutorial/blob/aa53b67efdd8019ffc3a64e18cec9b68cd048a3f/2-TokenCache/Console-TokenCache/Program.cs#L42) with `PublicClientApplicationBuilder`.